# Does aptitude use safe-upgrade or full-upgrade in visual mode?

Tags: debian, upgrade, aptitude

Sometimes I use [Aptitude](https://wiki.debian.org/Aptitude) in *visual mode*<sup>[1]</sup> to install and upgrade packages.

When I upgrade from the command line using `apt` or `aptitude` I often use `full-upgrade` instead of `safe-upgrade`<sup>[2]</sup> because I run the *testing* flavour of Debian, but which one is used in Aptitude visual mode?

Basically, what *really* happens when I press <kbd>U</kbd>?

If it's one way or another, is there a way to configure the default behaviour, or to decide manually which one to use?

---

<sup>[1] The GUI. Some call this a [TUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_user_interface).</sup>
<sup>[2] Formerly called *upgrade* and *dist-upgrade* respectively.</sup>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither.

When you press <kbd>U</kbd>, [every package which can be upgraded is flagged for upgrade, except for packages that are held back or would be upgraded to a forbidden version](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/aptitude/ch02s02s03.en.html). This isn’t the same as either `safe-upgrade` or `full-upgrade` on the command line, because conflicts aren’t resolved fully: the upgrade flagging can result in (tentatively) broken packages, which you’ll see indicated by the number of broken packages, but Aptitude won’t do anything about those breakages simply as a result of pressing <kbd>U</kbd>. You can resolve any conflicts manually, or you can ask Aptitude to [show you the various resolution possibilities](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/aptitude/ch02s03s03.en.html) using <kbd>e</kbd>, <kbd>.</kbd> and <kbd>,</kbd> to navigate, and <kbd>!</kbd> to apply a resolution.

In the code itself, the [<kbd>U</kbd> handling](https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/aptitude/blob/6e48f3cbfacfa64c0f2ca26fa21d2514e6684e14/src/ui.cc#L2034) is closer to [`safe-upgrade`](https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/aptitude/blob/6e48f3cbfacfa64c0f2ca26fa21d2514e6684e14/src/cmdline/cmdline_do_action.cc#L214) than to `full-upgrade`, because it ignores removals initially. But as mentioned above, it’s not *quite* the same.